# Angularjs refresh only angular.element

Tags: angularjs

i working with angularjs, and my web receive data from websocket each second, and now i using a `$scope.$apply` for refresh every time I get a fact, the problem is when my server send More information than usual the web page is very slow, and if i comment the `$scope.$apply` the web run fine.

I have something like this

```
$scope.ChangeData=function(str){
  //process.... take around 1ms
  //here i change a variable, with new info

  $scope.$apply();
 //here the process print 60-100ms
}
```

then i want to do it,

```
 $scope.ChangeData=function(str){
          //process.... take around 1ms
          //here i change a variable, with new info 
angular.element(document.getElementById(str.ID)).scope().$apply

         //I do this, I hope the process will only take a few ms
         //beacuse i change only the changed element  
        }
```

but i have a error in this part

> **Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined**

please help me..

**UPDATE**
[Example in plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IPSlk93tub68Kg2FZCfF?p=preview)

Comment: are you injecting `$scope` into your controller function?  Also, why do you need to call `$apply`?  If you're executing this within a promise or some other angular construct's logic, you shouldn't have to call `$apply`.  And as a note, it is **not** recommended to utilize the `angular.element(elem).scope()` type logic anywhere other than within a directive.  Consider using a service if that data needs to be consumed by another controller or use the `elem` argument supplied in your `link` function within the directive

Comment: if i no use `$apply`, the information no refresh until you click on the element,

Comment: ChangeData, as the name says, change the data,  But this information is not displayed until you make the `$apply` or `click`

Comment: Without seeing this within some context I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you recreate this in jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: @jusopi must tell angular to run digest somehow ... socket is not part of angular core

Comment: Make sure the element exists before getting the scope

Comment: the element exist, sorry for delay here is a example [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/IPSlk93tub68Kg2FZCfF?p=preview)

Comment: `if($scope.elements[i].id=str[0].id)` should be `if ($scope.elements[i].id === str[0].id)`. Post the actual code in the question.

Comment: looking at the sample you provided, I'm going to make some recommended changes assuming this is some messaging application.

Comment: yes @jusopi , the information change many times, the var change but the view no update, only update if `$scope.apply` is enable, then i looking a way for update the view only for 1 element

Answer (score -1):

*Without fully understanding the context of your application, I can only guess that this is a messaging type application.  This assumption is based on the fact that a) you're using a socket server to push updates to existing data on the UI and b) you're attempting to maintain existing UI already present.*

I took your plunkr and forked it with how I would approach this problem.  There are 2 things to realize:

- the `ItemsController` is dumbed down so that it only consumes a model coming from a service and the simulated push to update to said model
- the `itemsService` facilitates

  - storing the messages data
  - handles the push update

Because the `ng-repeat` is already charged with *watching* any changes in its target collection, you shouldn't have to do any of the `$scope.$apply` or `angular.element` stuff you were doing.  Each item in the `ng-repeat` will update the DOM for you.  That's its purpose.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qLeDuP0iaTUE16rY2KTl?p=preview

Comment: ng-repeat should be update, but it no happend... if i disable `$scope.$apply`,the view no update, until i make click

Comment: Angular is watching the collection, but it doesn't constantly loop over it to detect if something has changed. It only does that when $scope.$apply() is called. This usually happens automatically because angular does it after an ng-click, or a $http response comes in. But if you're not using any angular service, as the OP does, $scope.$apply() is necessary. Otherwise, you modify the scope without angular being aware of it.

Comment: @jusopi simple plunkr demonstrating it: http://plnkr.co/edit/53Uf98rVObdNAtCRqZCH?p=preview

Comment: exact @JBNizet , but exist a way for update without `$apply`, i have many lag

Comment: @JBNizet: If the OP were to wrap the update callback from the socket server (say via Faye) within his service, then it is indeed triggering a $digest.  That's exactly why I set up my plunkr that way, so as to illustrate a) separation of concerns and b) no need to call $apply from a controller.